# Почему при изменении KeyCode(vk=255) на KeyCode(char="q") все работает, а при попытке указать через vk=255 - нет?

Tags: python

Почему он не работает? Почему при изменении KeyCode(vk=255) на KeyCode(char="q") все работает, а при попытке указать через vk=255 - нет? Как мне это исправить?

```
import time
import threading
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode




TOGGLE_KEY = KeyCode(vk=255)
clicking = False
mouse = Controller()


def clicker():
    while True:
        if clicking:
            mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
        time.sleep(0.0001)


def toggle_event(key):
    if key == TOGGLE_KEY:
        global clicking
        clicking = not clicking


click_thread = threading.Thread(target=clicker)
click_thread.start()
with Listener(on_press=toggle_event) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: а что такое vk?

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html

Comment: потому что 255 код клавиши - совершенно не соответствует клавише q на клавиатуре [Изучайте коды](https://narvell.nl/keys)

Comment: @strawdog vk => Virtual Key

Comment: суть не в соответствии, какой бы код я не подставил, он не работает. У меня имеется мультимедийная клавиша 255 мне бы ее припихнуть а `q` я использовал чисто для примера.

Comment: Чисто для примера проверьте с обычной клавишей которую и приводите - всё сработает. а вот с вашей мультимедийной может ничего не срабатывать по целому ряду причин, из самых очевидных - 1) неверный код клавиши, 2) Клавиша имеет модификатор(ее код 255 + смещение)

Comment: KeyCode(char="q") - работает
KeyCode(vk=81) - не работает
KeyCode(vk="0x51") - не работает

Comment: `KeyCode(char='q')`, `KeyCode(char='Q')`, `KeyCode(vk=81)` и `KeyCode.from_vk(81)` возвращают один и тот же результат?